# If I expose IQueryable from my service layer, wouldn't the database calls be less if I need to grab information from multiple services?

Tags: linq, repository-pattern

If I expose IQueryable from my service layer, wouldn't the database calls be less if I need to grab information from multiple services?

For example, I'd like to display 2 separate lists on a page, `Posts` and `Users`. I have 2 separate services that provides a list of these. If both provides IQueryable, will they be joint in 1 database call? Each repository creates a context for itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's best to think of an `IQueryable<T>` as a single query waiting to be run.  So if you return 2 `IQueryable<T>` instances and run them in the controller, it wouldn't be any different than running them separably in their own service methods.  Each time you execute the `IQuerable<T>` to get results, it will run the query by itself independent of other `IQuerable<T>` objects.

The only time (as far as I know) it will make an impact if there is enough time between the two service calls that the database connection might close, but you would need a considerable amount of time in between the service calls for that to be the case.

Returning `IQuerable<T>` to the controller still has some usefulness, such as easier handling of paging and sorting (so sorting is done on the controller and is not done on the service layer which doesn't necessarily care about how data is sorted or paged).  This isn't a performance concern though, and people will disagree about if it's best to do this in the controller or not (I've seen reputable developers do this and give well thought out reasons why).

Answer (score 2):

No.  The best an IQueryable can do is reduce the number of calls within a singular database context.  An IQueryable will not cross contexts.

Personally, I don't use IQueryables past the repositories for a number of reasons:

1) I don't use the same domain objects as database objects, and seeing "no translation to SQL" pisses me off ;)

2) I don't like the necessary structure for IQueryables in views: foreach (var item in collection){var tempItem = item; code on tempItem}

3) I've come up with a method of passing generic filters to the data layer (LinqKit and PredicateBuilder are gods)

If these reasons don't apply to you, of course you should feel free to use IQueryables to whichever layer you desire.

Comment: As a person just getting into MVC I find your practices interesting and I would love to see your reasoning behind them... at the moment I feel like you've stated them as opinions rather than reasons. Please note that I'm not criticizing you for having an opinion, I just want to learn the rationale behind it.

Comment: They're mixed opinions/reasons.  #1 can lead to some irritating RUNTIME hangups if I filter an IQueryable<TDomain> on some TDomain.Property where said property does not correspond to a TDb.Property directly.  It wasn't as big of a deal in my last project, but my current project inherited a horrible database.  #2 is just pure personal aesthetics.  I developed #3 in response to said current project, and I'm seeing it's power for user generated predicates being applied even "easier" than with linq where statements.  So passing a predicate down is just as easy as applying a where to an IQueryable.

Answer (score 1):

Not with two different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely NO. It's a leaky abstraction.

It allows abominations like this:

```
q.Where(x=>{Console.WriteLine("fail");return true;});
```

Thing is - when exposing IQueryable, You are saying that Your data layer **fully** supports linq to objects.

Comment: Don't all ORMs do this now?  Please don't say "but what if you switch ORMs" because that never happens and if it does requires a bit re-write effort anyway.

Comment: @jfar they do not for sure. try for yourself. how would You parse writing to console into sql? and it screws up isolation too - simple thing like understanding what kind of indexes your DB needs would involve hunting down every query.

Comment: Subsonic, NHibernate, Entity Framework, Linq to Sql, Lightspeed all use linq.  Can't think of another popular ORM.  I don't understand what writing to the console or indexes has to do with using IQueryable<T> in your controllers.  Whether the code is in the controller or in a Service/Repository/HotNewRage you still have the same amount of places to look.

Comment: @jfar it's about **isolation**. but we can just ignore that. high coupling is our friend, duct tape programming kicks ass, programming is hard, let's go shopping...

Comment: @jfar you are right. it doesn't matter that much. similar story as with duct typing.

Answer (score 0):

If you make two method calls you will make two queries.

You can combine the methods into a single method which gets all the data at once.
If you are implementing the repository pattern you will have an easier time if you instantiate one database context per request.

Answer (score 0):

Your service layer is exactly that, a layer which serves up what you need.  Often times my service layers are named things like `SearchService` which has methods for returning every packaged collection I will ever need (the actual view models themselves).  And if I ever need a new search, my service layer gets a new method.  The backing for your service layer can then contain any data backing or persistence model you would like, be it a repository or Entity Framework provider, etc.

To answer your question though, the line needs to be drawn at the service layer, all queries need to be contained within it and only data returned.