# When would I use @Bean instead of @Component?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I'm confused as to a few things in Spring.

First, when would I want to use @Component over an explicit @Configuration class with a @Bean for what would have been a @Component?

The only reason I can think of for using @Component is to save myself the creation of a @Bean method in a @Configuration class. Are there other reasons?

That said, if I am using a @Configuration class it seems like I can hand code the wiring of these beans. IOW, where I did use @Inject on a @Component I can now explicitly specify dependencies in the @Bean constructor (when I create it in my bean method). So when would I want to use @Inject? I feel like I'm going down a rabbit hole here.

Are there any good tutorials or blogs that cover the best practices or rules for making these kinds of decisions?

Thanks

Comment: Please, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604298/spring-component-versus-bean

Comment: Yeah, that question actually piqued my interest. If that is true why would one want to use Component over Bean. It's what lead me to the question above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An example:

```
@Component
public class SomeComponent { }
```

The above will in practice create the same as:

```
public class SomeComponent { }
@Configuration
public class SomeComponentConfig {
    @Bean
    public SomeComponent someComponent() {
        return new SomeComponent();
    }
}
```

The advantage of `@Component` is clear: It is less code!

On the other hand, `@Bean` is powerful and has many use cases; for example if `SomeComponent` is in an existing library that you can't edit, or you simply don't want to clutter it with Spring or `@Inject`annotations.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that it is nice to keep stuff that requires specific configuration as a \@Bean. For example defining a redis host or database credentials. That allows you to change per-instance stuff in a configuration class. If it has no per-instance configuration you may as well just created a \@Component (or \@Named).