# What happen when creating bean from component classes in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Lets say i have a class Foo defined by @Component annotation:

```
@Component
public class Foo{
}
```

Then in configuration class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Configuration{

   @Bean
   public Foo foo(){
      return new Foo();
   }
```

I've ran it succeed but can some one explain the details of the concept here ? Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

Comment: Are you asking about the difference of `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Repository` and `@Controler`, or is your question about the componentscan-autowiring process?

Comment: some-what similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604298/spring-component-versus-bean

Comment: @Ralph in my knowledge , Bean and Component are different but quite do the same job, and i wonder why there weren't any conflicts?

Comment: So your question is, why there is no conflict between to two almost equal nammed and typed beans?