# Spring Bean is not autowired

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I have a problem with Spring bean `DefaultConfigurationService` initialization that is extended from `abstract` class. I am totally stuck.

Class hiearchy is as follows:

```
public interface ConfigurationService {
    TaxPayer getTaxPayer();
}
```

This class is mentioned to be useful for services that need to be initialized:

```
public abstract class BaseInitializationAwareService {

    private boolean initialized = false;

    public abstract void initialize();

    protected void checkInitialization() {
        if (!initialized) {
            initialize();
        }
    }

    protected void setInitialized() {
        this.initialized = true;
    }
}
```

This class acts as base class for Configuration service.

```
public abstract class BaseConfigurationService extends BaseInitializationAwareService implements ConfigurationService {


}
```

And with this bean, that acts as a configuration service, is a problem:

```
    public class DefaultConfigurationService extends BaseConfigurationService {

        private TaxPayerService taxPayerService;

        @Autowired
        public void setTaxPayerService(TaxPayerService taxPayerService) {
            Assert.notNull(taxPayerService);
            this.taxPayerService = taxPayerService;
        }

public void initialize() {
        Optional<TaxPayer> dbtaxPayer = taxPayerService.getActiveTaxPayer();
        if (!dbtaxPayer.isPresent()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Tax payer setting not found!");
        }
        this.taxPayer = dbtaxPayer.get();
        setInitialized();
    }

    // the rest omitted...
    }
```

when I'm creating `DefaultConfigurationService` bean:

```
@Bean
    public BaseConfigurationService configurationService() {
        DefaultConfigurationService configurationService = new DefaultConfigurationService();
        configurationService.initialize();
        return configurationService;
    }
```

then `taxPayerService` in `DefaultConfigurationService` is null - it seems that is not autowired.

**Can it be connected to the fact that `DefaultConfigurationService` is extended from abstract class?**

TaxPayer service bean:

```
@Bean
    public TaxPayerService taxPayerService() {
        DatabaseTaxPayerService taxPayer = new DatabaseTaxPayerService();
        return taxPayer;
    }
```

This bean is probably **never initialized**...

Thats is a exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig.ApiSecurity':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers'
>   parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'passwordRecoverController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through method 'setUserService' parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'defaultUserService': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through method 'setNotificationService' parameter
>   0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'notificationService': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurationService'
>   parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'configurationService' defined in class path
>   resource [com.example.config/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via
>   factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.example.services.BaseConfigurationService]: Factory
>   method 'configurationService' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

---

For example, bean that needs `BaseConfigurationService`:

```
    public class EmailNotificationService extends BaseService implements NotificationService {

        private BaseConfigurationService configurationService;

@Autowired
    public void setConfigurationService(BaseConfigurationService configurationService) {
        Assert.notNull(configurationService);
        this.configurationService = configurationService;
    }

    // the rest omitted... 
    }
```

---

**#update 1**

Bean initialization example with internal dependencies to another beans:

```
@Bean
    public TransactionDataService transactionDataService() {
        return new DefaultTransactionDataService();
    }
```

and `DefaultTransactionDataService`:

```
public class DefaultTransactionDataService implements TransactionDataService {
    private PrivateKeyService privateKeyService;

    @Autowired
    public void setPrivateKeyService(PrivateKeyService privateKeyService) {
        Assert.notNull(privateKeyService);
        this.privateKeyService = privateKeyService;
    }
}
```

and bean dependency

```
@Bean
    public PrivateKeyService privateKeyService() {
        return new DefaultPrivateKeyAwareService();
    }
```

and it **works**.

Comment: The problem is you are calling `initialize` from inside your `@Bean` method. That will be invoked before Spring even had a change on injecting the dependencies. Instead of calling the method yourself specify it as the `initMethod` in the `@Bean` method. That will make spring first create the bean, inject dependencies and then call the init method.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to your instruction to Spring how to initialize your bean:

> @Bean is used to explicitly declare a single bean, rather than letting Spring do it automatically as above. It decouples the declaration of the bean from the class definition, and lets you create and configure beans exactly how you choose.

So when you create instance of your class manually your have to set all class field manually as well.

It can be done like this:

```
@Bean
public BaseConfigurationService configurationService() {
    DefaultConfigurationService configurationService = new DefaultConfigurationService();
    configurationService.setTaxPayerService(taxPayerService());
    configurationService.initialize();
    return configurationService;
}
```

Or move dependency directly to constructor, so dependency of your `DefaultConfigurationService` will be more obvious:

```
@Bean
public BaseConfigurationService configurationService() {
    DefaultConfigurationService configurationService = new DefaultConfigurationService(taxPayerService());
    configurationService.initialize();
    return configurationService;
}
```

[Good description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604298/spring-component-versus-bean)

Comment: Thank you. Do you have some more information about your answer? I'm not really sure about it because the problem I described happens after I created mentioned abstract class. And in my app there are many beans that are initialized with `@Bean` annotation and have internal dependencies. And it worked well for me until now.

Comment: you can follow my recommendation or not. it's up you. i provided you with link with more extended description. Do you have `DefaultConfigurationService ` annotated with `@Component`? What time you get an exception? Where do you invoke your `configurationService()`?

Comment: @Sergei - maybe we don't understand earch other, please read my answer, I wrote that I have many beans that are initialized with `@Bean` annotation, have internal dependencies and these beans were initialized properly. Please see my #1 updated please.

Comment: i understood you, if create class with `new` you create it with usual java approach. do you understand difference between between spring object creation and plane java object creation?

Comment: Please see code I mentioned in my #1 update, it will be clear.

Comment: if you create bean with `new` : `new DefaultTransactionDataService()` nothing was injected by spring in its particular object. it's it

Comment: `@Bean` is basically the same as the XML `bean` declaration. If you have `@Autowired` fields Spring will inject those, you don't have to do anything manually. However if you are calling methods before spring has time to do dependency injection (which is the case here) nothing is injected.

Comment: @M.Deinum what do you mean `time to do dependency injection`? in both annotation and xml bean you are not autowiring (you wire explicit)

Comment: Not with `@Autowired` What you are proposing is to do all the wiring yourself, that basically beats the whole purpose of `@Autowired` Even with XML when you had `@Autowired` you only need to declare the bean and the annotation processors (when enabled) would do the rest.

Comment: @M.Deinum I just explain how to avoid null. To support all auto wired chain we have to use '@Component'

Comment: @SergiiGetman, please, do not edit your comments, later it doesn't make sense what the others reply to your previous comment meaning...

Comment: @user1315357 what exactly comment you mean?

Comment: `@Component` isn't mandatory for `@Autowired`. It applies to all beans registered regardless if they are detected by component scanning or manually created by `@Bean` methods or `bean` elements in XML configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum don't agree with you https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-bean-annotation

Comment: I suggest you do a little test... Create an xml file. Create 2 beans without `@Component` and add `@Autowired` on the fields. Just register them in xml, add `<context:annotation-config />` and load the xml file... The auto wiring will be done. You don't need component-scanning or `@Component` for that.

Comment: BTW the documentation you point at actually supports my claim. The same applies to beans created with `@Bean` they don't have to be `@Component`s or scanned and still be able to use `@Autowired`. As stated I suggest you do a little test. (Although I have been using Spring for ~ 14 years and written a couple of books about it I kind of know what I'm talking about :) ).

Comment: @M.Deinum are we on the same page ? : ) let's look at `@Bean
    public CoachService coachService() {
        return new CoachService();
    }` and `public class CoachService {
    @Autowired
    private CoachRepository coachRepository;` in this case autowired property `coachRepository` will be null, but if we inject this @Bean `coachService` somewhere else - yes, it can be autowired. And yes, I know that you are Spring expert that's why I was so surprised. but possibly i understood you in incorrect way : )

Comment: No it won't be null... In fact it cannot be null as in that case your application would blow up at the moment it started because it couldn't do auto wiring. When using java based configuration annotation processing is enabled by default (as opposed to xml based configuration which has to be told it needs to switch on annotation processing).