# Spring Boot: @Autowired is not working for one of the class

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I am developing OAuth implementation with Jwt tokens.
It's kind of weird but for class `TokenAuthenticationService` When I try to `Autowired` this class in a different package, I get
`Consider defining a bean of type 'com.company.security.TokenAuthenticationService' in your configuration.`
I did a workaround and added `@Bean TokenAuthenticationService` in that class.
Now when I am trying to initialize an interface in the `TokenAuthenticationService` class, it gives the same type of error for that interface. 
`Consider defining a bean of type 'com.company.security.UserService' in your configuration.`

ComponentScan annotation is configured like `@ComponentScan({"com.company"})`

What I am missing here and why?

Comment: Is `TokenAuthentificationService` class yours? Is it annotated with `@Component` or equivalend annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways to define beans for autowiring in your project.

With **classes defined by you**, you can use the [`@Component`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html) annotation (or, for service classes, [`@Service`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html) annotation) this way:

```
@Service
public class TokenAuthenticationService { ... }
```

If you are using **third party classes**, you can configure them in a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public MyProjectConfig {
    @Bean
    public ThirdPartyClass serviceClass() { new ThirdPartyClass(); }
}
```

(Using `@Bean` annotation is not a workround. You just need to understand its purpose...)

This way autowiring should work...

Pay attention to [difference between @Component and @Bean annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604298/spring-component-versus-bean).