# Can I use spring injection, for injecting into an enum?

Tags: java, spring, enums, inject

I am trying to use spring injection to inject into an enum. Like this:

```
public enum Car {
HONDA("Honda", "hondas") {
    @Inject
    Carparts carparts;

    @Override
    public List<Carpart> getCarparts() {
        return carparts.getCarpartsListings();
    }
};
//more logic here
}
```

My Carparts bean is defined as follows in the configuration class:

```
@Bean
@Singleton
public Carparts geCarparts() {
    return new Carparts();
}
```

But no matter what I get a null value for carparts injection.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works at all but *if* that works, then you'll have to make this enum at least a component s.t. it gets picked up by spring. This is not particularly a qualified answer but you need at least something like a [`@Component` annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6897038/826983) on a class that you want to inject into.

Comment: @StefanFalk isn't annotating a class with "Component" another way of making that class a bean? I did not know that a class needs to be annotated with "Component" even for injection.

Comment: `@Component` tells Spring that this class should be managed by Spring. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in/6897038#6897038) for more details but the essence is that Spring won't inject anything if you don't tell Spring to take care about a class.

Comment: Also [take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10604537/826983).

Comment: Still null, but when I have Carparts carparts = new Carparts(); it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried `@Autowired` instead of `@Inject`? Shouldn't make a difference but you can try. To be honest I have no idea if this will actually work on `enum` types at all. You'll have to wait for somebody who can answer that in more detail I'm afraid.

Comment: I think it's not possible and [this thread](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/85134-inject-a-dependency-into-an-enum) seems to confirm that. You'll have to consider a workaround I guess.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Tell your ultimate goal and we might help by provide a workaround. You cannot inject into an enum because enum's static final, and the inject process is happens after enum loaded

Comment: @StefanFalk I think you are right.

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I have a junit which uses powermock, because of which the code coverage is not showing up. So I was trying to create a wrapper around the class with static methods. Now I am trying to inject this wrapper in the enum, instead of the original class with static methods.

Comment: Your `Enum` should not contain logic. If it contains logic, then your design is wrong. Refactoring the logic part out. You test your util class which has static methods is enough.

Comment: a `Car` is not a finite designation that is known ahead of time, so an Enum is not an appropriate way to model it in any case. a _Honda_ is an _AutoMaker_, not a _Car_, and you would have to re-build your application when Koenigsegg entered the market. Use a `Class`.

Comment: @StephenP I used car and honda as examples they are not the names I have actually used, I appreciate your suggestion thanks :)

Comment: Why has this been marked as duplicate? It is not similar to any of the question feeling unwelcome has marked here. He definitely is very unwelcoming.

Comment: I disagree with the statement that an `enum` should contain no logic. Check Joshua Bloch's usage of Enums in Effective Java, there are some helpful patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a workaround with an inner static class that will be a Spring component, inject it and set `carparts` for entire `Car EnumSet`.

```
public enum Car {
    private Carparts carparts;

    @Component
    public static class CarPartsInjector {
        @Inject
        private Carparts carparts;

        @PostConstruct
        public void construct() {
            for (Car car: EnumSet.allOf(Car.class))
               car.setCarparts(carparts);
        }

        private void setCarparts(Carparts carparts) {
            this.carparts = carparts;
        }
    //...

}
```

In general, I think this is not a proper solution.

The problem here is **Data Model**.

The `Car` shouldn't be an enum. It thould be a class with list of `Carparts`, `enum` as type like `CarType` or `ManufacturerType`.