# Getting Exception while creating beans using @Bean Spring annotation

Tags: java, spring

I was trying to understand difference between `@component` and `@Bean` in `Spring framework`, and referred to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604298/spring-component-versus-bean).

Based on the answer, I got a fair understanding, and tried to reinforce the concept by implementing a simple example (to check whether I really understood the concept).

The below is the code which I wrote. I wanted to see `@Bean` for "third party" libs (so that it can be instantiated using `@Bean` annotation)

```
package com.example.thirdparty.code;

public class ThirdPartyUtil {

    public ThirdPartyUtil() {
    }

    public void print(String str) {
        System.out.println("String passed is --> " + str);

    }
}
```

In above, I tried to simulate a "third party lib/class - NON spring" which isn't a spring based (and so there won't be any `@component` in that class.

Now, below is the main application which I created:

```
package com.example.spring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.thirdparty.code.ThirdPartyUtil;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.spring" })
@Component
public class SpringBasedMainApp {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Autowired
    private static ThirdPartyUtil thirdPartyUtil;

    @Bean
    public ThirdPartyUtil beanThirdPartyUtil() {
        try {
            Class c = getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("com.example.thirdparty.code.ThirdPartyUtil");
            return (ThirdPartyUtil) ctx.getBean(c);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Exception");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringBasedMainApp.class);

        System.out.println("thirdPartyUtil is " + thirdPartyUtil);

    }
}
```

I was hoping that using `@Bean` annotation, it would create `ThirdPartyUtil` as Spring bean, and then inject using `@Autowired` into field `thirdPartyUtil`.

However, when I run this program, I got altogether a surprising exception, listed below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beanThirdPartyUtil' defined in com.example.spring.SpringBasedMainApp: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.thirdparty.code.ThirdPartyUtil]: Factory method 'beanThirdPartyUtil' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beanThirdPartyUtil': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:88)
    at com.example.spring.SpringBasedMainApp.main(SpringBasedMainApp.java:41)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.thirdparty.code.ThirdPartyUtil]: Factory method 'beanThirdPartyUtil' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beanThirdPartyUtil': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beanThirdPartyUtil': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:215)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1112)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1101)
    at com.example.spring.SpringBasedMainApp.beanThirdPartyUtil(SpringBasedMainApp.java:33)
    at com.example.spring.SpringBasedMainApp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d93c67f4.CGLIB$beanThirdPartyUtil$0(<generated>)
    at com.example.spring.SpringBasedMainApp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d93c67f4$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9349d69b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at com.example.spring.SpringBasedMainApp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d93c67f4.beanThirdPartyUtil(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 15 more
```

I didn't understand why it is giving this exception. I am creating an applicationContext using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` and passing the necessary details to it.

I expected it to work, however got the above exception (which I have seen maiden time).

Why has this exception been thrown, is my understanding not correct about `@Bean`?

Comment: JB Nizet already wrote the reason, I just want to add a side not here:
Autowiring static fields also won't work. It probably not throwing an exception, but will always be null.

Comment: @PowR: Thanks for the info. I realized after running the sample app. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal of the `@Bean` annotation is to annotate a method whose responsibility is to create an object, that will then be registered as a bean by Spring.

But inside your method, you ask Spring (using `ctx.getBean()`) to give you the bean that you're currently creating. So you get that exception.

Here's what your methd should look like:

```
@Bean
public ThirdPartyUtil beanThirdPartyUtil() {
    return new ThirdPartyUtil();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. You have answered my other questions too in past. Your highly technical skills helps a lot.

Answer (score -1):

To extend @JB Nizet answer, instantiate your third party class in spring constructor like below.

```
@Autowired
private static ThirdPartyUtil thirdPartyUtil;

@Autowired
public SpringBean() {
    this.thirdPartyUtil = new ThirdPartyUtil();
}
```