# What's the difference between @Bean and @Component?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm learning Spring Boot recently, But I'm quite confused by `@Bean` annotation and `@Component` annotation.

Now I want to change the page language by clicking on language buttons. So I create a `LocaleResolver`:

```java
public class MyLocaleResolver implements LocaleResolver {

    @Override
    public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        String lang = httpServletRequest.getParameter("lang"); 
        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault(); 
        if(lang != null && lang.length() !=0){ 
            String[] splitted = lang.split("-");
            locale = new Locale(splitted[0], splitted[1]);
        }
        return locale;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLocale(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Locale locale) {}
}
```

And in the configuration class `MyMvcConfig`:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyMvcConfig {
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
        return new MyLocaleResolver();
    }
}
```

And it works properly, my own implementation replaces the default `LocaleResolver` in `WebMvcAutoConfiguraion`. But if I remove the configuration class and add `@Component` annotation to `MyLocaleResolver` class, then the container will still use the default `LocaleResolver`. Why this happen?

Comment: This question does not seem duplicate of [it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10604298/4506703).

Comment: I think [`DispatcherServlet` implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L124-L127) helps you.