# Spring beans creation

Tags: java, spring

What is the difference between `@Component` and `@Bean`s in `@Configuration` classes? Which one should I use?

I tried both ways: in any way I can get singleton beans or bean factories (e.g. prototype scope). The app works correctly in any solution, so i guess this question is a matter of architecture.

Comment: It's better to use @Bean in configuration classes. See here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604298/spring-component-versus-bean