Spring Boot - Bean configuration
I am trying to connect to a database which will hold log in information for my application.
I keep getting this error:

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:
Field userDetailsService in com.neet.HealthTracker.Security.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'com.neet.HealthTracker.Model.MyUserDetailsService' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.neet.HealthTracker.Model.MyUserDetailsService' in your configuration.
The following is my code:
package com.neet.HealthTracker.Model;

import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;


//This sets the users

public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private IMyUserRepo repo;
    
    // this searchs the DB for the username
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<MyUsers> user = repo.findByUsername(username);
        if(user.isPresent()){
            var userObj = user.get();
            return User.builder()
            .username(userObj.getUsername())
            .password(userObj.getPassword())
            .build();
        }else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        
    }

}





 package com.neet.HealthTracker.Security;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer;
//import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
//import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
//import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import com.neet.HealthTracker.Model.MyUserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig  {
    
    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    // customises the authorisation for the application
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
    return httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(registry-> {
        registry.requestMatchers("/" ).permitAll(); //accessible by everyone
        registry.requestMatchers("/user/**").authenticated(); // URL's starting with user will require authentication
        registry.anyRequest().authenticated(); // any URL not mentioned above will require authentication
    })
    .formLogin(AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer::permitAll)//customises the log in information
    .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        return userDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        //this is a Data Access Object (from Spring Core) - explicity loads data from the DB and used for data authentication
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    // For prototyping - In memory user authentication is used **NOT TO BE USED IN
    // PRODUCTION**

    // @Bean
    // public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
    // UserDetails user1 = User.builder()
    // .username("user1")
    // .password("$2a$12$hB/XMcoVlAA1bTWOZlwFee739Vh3036QXVEMWjkIoq7ikm0dNqGx6")
    // //for the password above - I used an online BCrpt generator
    // .roles("USER")
    // .build();

    // UserDetails user2 = User.builder()
    // .username("user2")
    // .password("$2a$12$c/QZMLaV1eg3Jg2xWOFj4uFgDKlZJw3PC6FRZWOlEB/Z/XUNWnmHq")
    // .roles("USER")
    // .build();

    // return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user1,user2);

    // }

}

This is my file structure:

I cannot figure out what is wrong.

You are missing @Service / @Component annotation on MyUserDetailsService

But then I get:
2024-06-20T15:23:47.720+01:00 ERROR 30984 --- [HealthTracker] [restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in class path resource [com/neet/HealthTracker/Security/SecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService]: Factory method 'userDetailsService' threw exception with message: null

Remove Bean of userDetailsService which you created in your Security Config

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604298/spring-component-versus-bean

It seems to be two things. You need to annotate your service class with a Stereotype annotation like @Service so Spring can include it in the context, next you seem to have 2 implementations of UserDetails service , one which is in the bean format , the other is your custom class. There should be only one implementation and also annotated with @Bean or similar so it can be picked up by Spring.

I removed the UserDetailsService Bean in the Security config class. Thanks for your help

Add @Component or @Service to MyUserDetailsService
and remove 
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
   return userDetailsService();
}

