# SpringMvc Annotations For Pojo

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

What are the annotations you would use on your POJOs, DAO and interfaces, implementated interfaces classes if using annotation based configurations. I am new to using annotations i know in the applicationContext.xml you would include

Also what is defined in the servlet-context.xml when using annotations do you keep your bean definitions eg.

```
<bean name="/welcome.htm" class="com.test.WelcomeController">
        <property name="welcomeManager" ref="welcomeManager"/>  
 </bean>
```

I am reading the Springsource docs and i am not seeing any configurations for the POJO', DAO, Interfaces and implemented Interfaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a POJO I would use `@Component`, for a DB-backed DAO, I would use `@Repository`(you get persistence exception translation). For more info see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in).