# Is Spring annotation @Controller same as @Service?

Tags: spring, service, controller

Is Spring annotation `@Controller` same as `@Service`?

I have idea about `@Controller` which can be used for `URL` mapping and invoking business logic.

while `@Service` used to annotate service class which contains business logic.

Can I use `@Controller` instead of `@Service` to annotate Service class?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

No, they are pretty different from each other.

Both are different specializations of **@Component** annotation (in practice, they're two different implementations of the same interface) so both can be discovered by the classpath scanning (if you declare it in your XML configuration)

**@Service** annotation is used in your service layer and annotates classes that perform service tasks, often you don't use it but in many case you use this annotation to represent a best practice. For example, you could directly call a DAO class to persist an object to your database but this is horrible. It is pretty good to call a service class that calls a DAO. This is a good thing to perform the separation of concerns pattern.

**@Controller** annotation is an annotation used in Spring MVC framework (the component of Spring Framework used to implement Web Application). The @Controller annotation indicates that a particular class serves the role of a controller. The @Controller annotation acts as a stereotype for the annotated class, indicating its role. The dispatcher scans such annotated classes for mapped methods and detects @RequestMapping annotations.

So looking at the Spring MVC architecture you have a DispatcherServlet class (that you declare in your XML configuration) that represent a front controller that dispatch all the HTTP Request towards the appropriate controller classes (annotated by @Controller). This class perform the business logic (and can call the services) by its method. These classes (or its methods) are typically annotated also with **@RequestMapping** annotation that specify what HTTP Request is handled by the controller and by its method.

For example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/appointments")
public class AppointmentsController {

    private final AppointmentBook appointmentBook;

    @Autowired
    public AppointmentsController(AppointmentBook appointmentBook) {
        this.appointmentBook = appointmentBook;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, Appointment> get() {
        return appointmentBook.getAppointmentsForToday();
    }
```

This class is a controller.

This class handles all the HTTP Request toward "/appointments" "folder" and in particular the get method is the method called to handle all the GET HTTP Request toward the folder "/appointments".

I hope that now it is more clear for you.

Comment: Very nice explanation. One point to mention, (at)controller classes need not have (at)RequestMapping,(at)RequestMapping can be method level also.

Comment: Can I mix them in single class definition? Or is it better to implement them as separate classes?

Answer (score 43):

If you look at the definitions of `@Controller`, `@Service` annotations, then you'll find that these are special type of `@Component` annotation.

```
@Component
public @interface Service {
    ….
}
```

```
@Component
public @interface Controller {
    …
}
```

---

***So what's the difference?***

> **@Controller**

The `@Controller` annotation indicates that a particular class serves the role of a controller. The `@Controller` annotation acts as a stereotype for the annotated class, indicating its role.

***What’s special about @Controller?***

You cannot switch this annotation with any other like `@Service` or `@Repository`, even though they look same. 
The dispatcher scans the classes annotated with `@Controller` and detects `@RequestMapping` annotations within them. You can only use `@RequestMapping` on `@Controller` annotated classes.

---

> **@Service**

`@Services` hold business logic and call method in repository layer.

***What’s special about @Service?***

Apart from the fact that it is used to indicate that it's holding the business logic, there’s no noticeable specialty that this annotation provides, but who knows, spring may add some additional exceptional in future.

Linked answer: [What's the difference between @Component, @Repository & @Service annotations in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38549461/2815219)

Answer (score 7):

No, `@Controller` is not the same as `@Service`, although they both are specializations of `@Component`, making them both candidates for discovery by classpath scanning. The `@Service` annotation is used in your service layer, and `@Controller` is for Spring MVC controllers in your presentation layer. A `@Controller` typically would have a URL mapping and be triggered by a web request.

Answer (score 5):

@Service vs @Controller

@Service : class is a "Business Service Facade" (in the Core J2EE patterns sense), or something similar.

@Controller : Indicates that an annotated class is a "Controller" (e.g. a web controller).

----------Find Usefull notes on Major Stereotypes
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html

@interface Component

```
  @Target(value=TYPE)
     @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
     @Documented
    public @interface Component
```

Indicates that an annotated class is a component. Such classes are considered as candidates for auto-detection when using annotation-based configuration and classpath scanning.

### Other class-level annotations may be considered as identifying a component as well, typically a special kind of component: e.g. the @Repository annotation or AspectJ's @Aspect annotation.

**@interface Controller**

```
@Target(value=TYPE)
 @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
 @Documented
 @Component
public @interface Controller
```

Indicates that an annotated class is a "Controller" (e.g. a web controller).

### This annotation serves as a specialization of @Component, allowing for implementation classes to be autodetected through classpath scanning. It is typically used in combination with annotated handler methods based on the RequestMapping annotation.

@***interface Service***

```
@Target(value=TYPE)
 @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
 @Documented
 @Component
public @interface Service
```

Indicates that an annotated class is a "Service", originally defined by Domain-Driven Design (Evans, 2003) as "an operation offered as an interface that stands alone in the model, with no encapsulated state."
May also indicate that a class is a "Business Service Facade" (in the Core J2EE patterns sense), or something similar. This annotation is a general-purpose stereotype and individual teams may narrow their semantics and use as appropriate.

### This annotation serves as a specialization of @Component, allowing for implementation classes to be autodetected through classpath scanning.

***@interface Repository***

```
@Target(value=TYPE)
 @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
 @Documented
 @Component
public @interface Repository
```

Indicates that an annotated class is a "Repository", originally defined by Domain-Driven Design (Evans, 2003) as "a mechanism for encapsulating storage, retrieval, and search behavior which emulates a collection of objects".
Teams implementing traditional J2EE patterns such as "Data Access Object" may also apply this stereotype to DAO classes, though care should be taken to understand the distinction between Data Access Object and DDD-style repositories before doing so. This annotation is a general-purpose stereotype and individual teams may narrow their semantics and use as appropriate.

A class thus annotated is eligible for Spring DataAccessException translation when used in conjunction with a PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor. The annotated class is also clarified as to its role in the overall application architecture for the purpose of tooling, aspects, etc.

As of Spring 2.5, this annotation also serves as a specialization of @Component, allowing for implementation classes to be autodetected through classpath scanning.

Answer (score 1):

I already answered similar question on here [Here is the Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in/26174094#26174094)

No both are different.

@Service annotation have use for other purpose and @Controller use for other.
Actually Spring @Component, @Service, @Repository and @Controller annotations are used for automatic bean detection using classpath scan in Spring framework, but it
doesn't ,mean that all functionalities are same.
@Service: It indicates annotated class is a Service component in the business layer.

@Controller: Annotated class indicates that it is a controller components, and mainly used at presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a *@service* as *@Controller*.

You can **NOT** declare an *@Controller* as *@Service*

***@Service***

It is regular. You are just declaring class as a Component.

***@Controller***

It is a little more special than Component.
The *dispatcher* will search for *@RequestMapping* here. 
So a class annotated with @Controller, will be additionally empowered with declaring URLs through which APIs are called

Answer (score 1):

- Controller will handle the navigation between the different views. Your mappings request mappings are handled with the help of controller.
- Service interacts directly with the repository where usually the business logic is performed. You can add, delete, remove etc at the service layer

Answer (score 0):

No you can't they are different. When the app was deployed your controller mappings would be borked for example.

Why do you want to anyway, a controller is **not** a service, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

From Spring In Action

> As you can see, this class is annotated with @Controller. On its own, @Controller doesn’t do much. Its primary purpose is to identify this class as a component for component scanning. Because HomeController is annotated with @Controller, Spring’s component scanning automatically discovers it and creates an instance of HomeController as a bean in the Spring application context.
>
> In fact, a handful of other annotations (including @Component, @Service, and @Repository) serve a purpose similar to @Controller. You could have just as effectively annotated HomeController with any of those other annotations, and it would have still worked the same. The choice of @Controller is, however, more descriptive of this component’s role in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Both are special form of @**Component** annotation.
Both @controller and @serviec, share same functionalities of @component annotation along with their own functionalities.

@**Controller** is a class-level annotation and it marks the class as web request handlers. For further explanation you can refer to this website: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller

@**Service** is also a class-level annotation and it contains a business logic.
For further explanation you can refer to this website: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-repository-service