# '@Inject thread bean in @Service' or '@Inject service bean in @Component', which is more reasonable architecture?

Tags: multithreading, spring, architecture, dependency-injection, javabeans

I am using SpringFramework for web server.

Sometimes I need to do asynchronous task to implement certain function.

Usually, I prefer to use

- @Inject @Component(which is implements Runnable) in @Service.

But I am not sure is it OK or not.

So I got a question just like the title.

- '`@Inject thread bean in @Service`'

OR

- '`@Inject service bean in @Component`'

I want to know which way is more frequently uses.

Thanks in advance:D

Have a good Day!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Based on edited question and commentary the answer has been changed.

@Component is generic
@Service is specific

@Inject is replaced by @Autowired

You always want to use @Autowired @Service instead of other combinations.

For architectural differences you will only get information from the API documents themselves.

for further detail check this out:

[What's the difference between @Component, @Repository & @Service annotations in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But my question is not what is different between '@Inject' and '@Autowired', it is about architecture perspectives.