# Call a spring @service from another project

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, wsdl

I've been studying **Spring MVC 4** and I understand that Spring have several annotations to develop faster. [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in) explains very well the relation between @Component, @Service, @Repository and @Controller. My questions are:

1. Can a **@service** class be called from another machine as a common wsdl service? For example, from a standalone app that is the client of the service.
2. Or is **@service** annotation just to mark the use of a class?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotation @Service is only a special version of @Component annotation and its purpose is not providing a remote access to implementation.

As mentioned in documentation, @Service annotation helps the class to be auto detected during the classpath scanning (see the [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html)) and processed by some tools.
Also check the explanation on [Spring's forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/36830-what-is-the-service-annotation).

Comment: Can I put both annotations @service and @webservice?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would advice you to annotate service implementation with @Service annotation, and inject it into the endpoint implementation (check http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html). In this way, you can expose your service implementation with different remoting technologies.

Answer (score 3):

The methods in class annotated with @Service cannot be called from outside, but it is common practice to add another layer generally called facade on top of the layer where you have your classes annotated with @Service(generally called as service layer). Using this facade you can expose your services in different ways like REST, SOAP etc.

Comment: Now it's very clear that I need an extra layer to separate functions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be called by using @service you need to annotate the class with @Webservice to expose it to the outside world

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse javax `@WebService` with Spring `@Service` which is defined [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html). Although both are called *service*.
`@Service`'s purpose is simply:

> This annotation serves as a specialization of @Component, allowing for implementation classes to be autodetected through classpath scanning.

So, since `@WebService` is for *WSDLs* (external access), a `@Service`is for Spring's internal use.
If you want to access "Services" from other machines, you have to write a `@WebService` or use `@RequestMapping` with `SpringMVC`.