# Autowired bean is null in thread location

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, javabeans

how can I access to exampleService from the thread  ? In new thread is null. ExampleService is an annotated @Service class. SessionFactory I set from dao and it is no null.

```
public class ExampleInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    ExampleService exampleService;

    public void setExampleService(ExampleService exampleService) {
        this.exampleService = exampleService;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) {
        new Thread(new SimpleThread(exampleService)).start();
    }

    protected class SimpleThread implements Runnable {
    protected ExampleService exampleService;

        public SimpleThread() {
        };
        public SimpleThread(ExampleService exampleService) {
      this.exampleService = exampleService;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
                    exampleService.method(); // is null at this location                        
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is `ExampleInterceptor ` also anotated as Controler or Service? Do youhave the `context:scan` activated in your config?

Comment: yes, class is in context scan path, exampleInterceptor is not annotated

Comment: Then anotate the class with `@Service and try again.

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: where you construct `ExampleInterceptor`

Comment: It is empty to begin with in the first place. The `EmptyInterceptor` isn't a Spring managed bean but managed by Hibernate. This results in `@Autowired` not being processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Annotate the Service Class with @Service, And for using that object you need to Autowire it.
If i am not wrong, In your "SimpleThread" class, you are using not autowiring the property
"protected ExampleService exampleService", which is a not having @Autowired annotation.
[@Service, @Controller, @Repository & @Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in)