# Spring Boot JPA - No qualifying bean of type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm learning Spring and things were going well but suddenly running into this issue where it cannot find a qualified bean. Hitting the wall, even in a new app I'm getting this.

Let me know if you need more, going to take a break! I must be missing something very simple.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
  No qualifying bean of type [com.alco.repository.ContactRepository]
  found for dependency [com.alco.repository.ContactRepository]:
  expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
  Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

My dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Contact class:

```
package com.example.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Contact implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1340978779095092824L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private String id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String address;
private String phoneNumber;
private String email;

}
```

The simple interface:

```
package com.alco.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.alco.entity.Contact;

public interface ContactRepository extends JpaRepository<Contact, String> {

}
```

Comment: Is `com.alco.repository` as sub package of your app (main class with `@SpringBootApplication`? If not, it's not picking it up there. Maybe adding `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.alco.repository"})` to your main app fixes the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're missing enabling of the JPA repositories:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ...)
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = ...)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = ...)
public class ... {
}
```

This would be for your configuration class.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see is this; please try with changing JpaRepository with Repository

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository

public interface ContactRepository extends Repository<Contact, String> {
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to annotate your repository with `@Repository`, otherwise Spring will not manage your Repository class.

Do not use the more generic `@Component`, as it may lead to different behavior, e.g. in Exception Management. As an example, look at [this parte of the Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/annotation/PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.html).

Excerpt:

> The postprocessor automatically looks for all exception translators
>   (implementations of the PersistenceExceptionTranslator interface) and
>   advises all beans marked with the @Repository annotation so that the
>   discovered translators can intercept and apply the appropriate
>   translation on the thrown exceptions.

Also, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in), in the future you might have back-compatibility issues.

As an alternative, you can use @EnableJpaRepositories and specify where Spring should be looking for repositories.

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary, there is no annotation in any of the examples ([CityRepository.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa/src/main/java/sample/data/jpa/service/CityRepository.java), [boot jpa getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)). The generated code that magically implements these interfaces and that is autowired instead of the interface is properly annotated with `@Repository` and such.

Comment: This is not necessary for Spring Data JPA repository interfaces, only for Spring Beans (classes), which are used as part of a repository layer.

Comment: I think that either you use that annotation or put EnableJpaRepositories with appropriate attribute. Spring is telling you that it cannot find the interface, so help it.

Comment: This isn't necessary. The only thing needed is to enable the JPA repositories.