# Using repository annotation when implementing JpaRepostiory in Spring

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-data-jpa

I'm not sure if I understand it correctly so want to clarify.
If I want to create a repository for my entity eg.:

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Id> {}
```

Should I annotate it with @Repository? According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in) @Repository annotation translates exceptions from SQL to persistence ones but doesn't JpaRepostiory already do that? What's the best practice - to annotate or not?

Comment: No, you don't need to when using Spring Data JPA. The Spring Data infrastructure scans for all interfaces extending `Repository` and automatically generates proxied implementations for them.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918181/why-isnt-necessary-repository-for-this-spring-boot-web-app

Answer (score 29, accepted):

While using `JpaRepository` you don't need to annotate the interface with `@Repository`

It is just an interface and the concrete implementation is created dynamically as a proxy object by Spring and the JDBC Exceptions are handled there.

You need to use `@Repository` when you create a Custom DAO, so that spring creates a bean and handles the exception properly.