# Why isn't necessary @Repository for this Spring Boot web app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm learning about Spring Boot and JPA, Spring Data Rest, H2 database and I have found a tutorial. I try to understand it and it is an easy example but I don't understand something. Why isn't it necessary to put `@Repository` or `@Component` in the AlienRepo class?

The repo object is injected in the **AlienController** class, and I know from previous tutorials that you need to use `@Component` or `@Repository`. I thought that it is mandatory to use this annotation.

The controller:

```
package com.dgs.springbootjpa.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.dgs.springbootjpa.dao.AlienRepo;
import com.dgs.springbootjpa.model.Alien;

@Controller
public class AlienController {

    @Autowired
    AlienRepo repo;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {

        return "home.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/addAlien")
    public String addAlien(Alien alien) {

        repo.save(alien);
        return "home.jsp";
    }

}
```

The POJO:

```
package com.dgs.springbootjpa.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Alien {

    @Id
    private int aid;

    private String aname;

    public int getAid() {
        return aid;
    }
    public void setAid(int aid) {
        this.aid = aid;
    }
    public String getAname() {
        return aname;
    }
    public void setAname(String aname) {
        this.aname = aname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "Alien [aid=" + aid + ", aname=" + aname + "]";
    }
}
```

The dao interface:

```
package com.dgs.springbootjpa.dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.dgs.springbootjpa.model.Alien;

public interface AlienRepo extends CrudRepository<Alien, Integer> {

}
```

You can see that in the **AlienRepo** interface there is not `@Repository` or `@Component` and the code is working successfully.

Thank you!

Update---------------------------------------------

I want to fetch data from database and I add the below code. I want to ask you why @RequestParam isn't mandatory? If I delete the @RequestParam the app is working successfully.

```
@RequestMapping("/getAlien")
public ModelAndView addAlien(@RequestParam int aid) {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("showAlien");
    Alien alien = repo.findById(aid).orElse(new Alien()); 
    mv.addObject(alien); 
    return mv;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you notice, [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) has [@NoRepositoryBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/NoRepositoryBean.html) annotation and this annotation makes [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) an intermediate interface. An intermediate interface is basically adds
general functionality for your derived repositories.

If any class annotated with `@NoRepositoryBean` Spring Data does not create instances at run-time. Because it's intermediate class and it's created to add functionality for the derived class.

If you extend an interface that has `@NoRepositoryBean` and your derived interface doesn't have `@NoRepositoryBean` Spring knows that you are trying to use that functionality in your real Repository interface so adding [@Repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html) annotation is verbose.

---

Edit: Why @RequestParam isn't mandatory?

From [the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-methods) you can see "Controller method argument" table, the last row of the table says:

Any other argument :

> If a method argument is not matched to any of the above, by default it
>   is resolved as an [@RequestParam](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestparam) if it is a simple type, as
>   determined by [BeanUtils#isSimpleProperty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#isSimpleProperty-java.lang.Class-), or as an
>   @ModelAttribute otherwise.

So if you omit annotation for "Controller Method Argument" and you don't write something like [@MatrixVariable](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-matrix-variables), [@PathVariable](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-refe) or [@RequestParam](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestparam).
It's default a `@RequestParam`.

Comment: I’m very grateful to you for your help! Can you help me with the update please? Why @RequestParam isn't mandatory?

Comment: Glad to help, Elvis! I have updated my answer, I hope it can help again.

Answer (score 5):

`@Component` and `@Repository` can be used on classes to use them as Spring Beans. However, `AlienRepo` is not a class, it's an interface which extends a Spring Data interface. Spring Data doesn't use annotations, it detects the interfaces by scanning the classpath and looking at the hierarchy of interfaces to see if a Spring Data interface is extended. If this is the case, it creates an implementation for each interface during runtime, which is then added to the application context as Spring Bean. That's why you don't need any annotations on a Spring Data interface.

Answer (score 3):

Your `@SpringBootApplication` brings in the effect of `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public @interface SpringBootApplication
```

This annotation will guess and auto configure beans.

> Auto-configuration for Spring Data's JPA Repositories.
>   Activates when there is a bean of type DataSource configured in the context, the Spring Data JPA JpaRepository type is on the classpath, and there is no other, existing JpaRepository configured.
>
> Once in effect, the auto-configuration is the equivalent of enabling JPA repositories using the EnableJpaRepositories annotation.
>
> This configuration class will activate after the Hibernate auto-configuration.

```
public class JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration {

}
```

When you add data-jpa dependency, `JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration` is triggered and bring effect of `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation to your app

[Your repository then auto-configured:](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-spring-data-jpa-repositories)

> Spring Data repositories usually extend from the Repository or CrudRepository interfaces. If you use auto-configuration, repositories are searched from the package containing your main configuration class (the one annotated with @EnableAutoConfiguration or @SpringBootApplication) down.

Comment: The question is about `@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository` _annotation_, not about `org.springframework.data.repository.Repository` interface

Comment: @Lu55 OP question is " Why isn't it necessary to put @Repository or @Component in the AlienRepo class" and I explained why Spring can do it automatically (automatic register Repository/CrudRepository sub-interface via `@EnableJpaRepositories`). And honestly, I don't even know why the above answer is accepted lol

Answer (score 1):

Your `AlienRepo` class extends `CrudRepository`, so Spring will be able to skim over the packages specified in the configuration and find repositories.

As a side note, you can drop `@Autowired` if there is exactly one constructor `AlienController(AlienRepo)`, Spring can figure that out as well.