# Getting: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'

Tags: java

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or need to add? Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's a picture of my project structure.

**User.java**

```
package org.codigo.entites;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String fname;
private String lname;
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}
public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}
public String getLname() {
    return lname;
}
public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
}
public User(String fname, String lname) {
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
}
public User() {
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [id=" + id + ", fname=" + fname + ", lname=" + lname + "]";
}
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
package org.codigo.repositories;

import org.codigo.entites.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

Comment: your `UserRepository` is interface, you cannot create bean for interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever Spring says `Unsatisfied dependency`, it does not know how to obtain an instance of the desired type.

To let Spring know and even implement your repository (just the interface), you should

add `@EnableJpaRepositories` to `MyAppApplication`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackage = "org.codigo.repositories")
public class MyAppApplication implements CommandLineRunner { ... }
```

This seems like magic at first - behind the scenes Spring will instantiate a dynamic proxy for your repository which intercepts all method calls and finds out what to do, based on the called method's name, its parameters and return type.

Reference:

- [Spring Boot / Data Access / Use Spring Data Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-use-spring-data-repositories)
- [Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation / JPA Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.repositories)

Comment: Voting it up now. Quick question: Wasn't the Repository annotation supposed to be ONLY for classes?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691697/using-repository-annotation-when-implementing-jparepostiory-in-spring it's only relevant to repositories not implementing the interface `Repository` (and `JpaRepository` extends that too). I will remove that from my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your `UserRepository` is interface, you cannot create bean for interface

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>
```

Declare `UserRepository` as class with method implementations and annotate with `@Repository` annotation, if `JpaRepository` is interface then you should use `implements` keyword

```
@Repository
public class UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>
```

Comment: It worked! thank you. Quick question: Do you why findOne and delete dont work with my version of spring-boot? I commented those methods out, but I want to use them but I get an error. Do you know what can be causing the error?

Comment: Yes, those are built-in methods . They are inside UserController Class

Comment: In the class `UserRepository` you need to provide implementation for those methods, `JpaRepository` is an interface ?

Comment: Or do you know another way of finding a user by his ID and deleting a user by his ID using spring

Comment: can you update your `JpaRepository` code in post?, if it is an interface you need to implement methods of interface in implemented class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html