# Spring Data JPA Autowired repository returns null

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using the following repository and controller to retrieve some records from the DB:

```
public interface TableARepository extends CrudRepository<TableA, Long>{
    @Query(value = "SELECT r FROM TableA r  WHERE r.Id = :Id", nativeQuery = true)
    public Rater getTableAById(@Param("Id") Long Id);
}

@RestController
public class TableAController {
    @Autowired
    TableARepository tableARepository;
    
    @GetMapping(value="/GetTableAById")
    public TableA getTableAById(@RequestParam String email) {
        TableA tableA = new TableA();
        tableA = tableARepository.getTableAById(email);
        return tableA;
    }
}
```

The following error appears once i invoke the REST api:

```
Cannot invoke com.TableARepository.getTableAById(Long) because this.tableARepository is null
```

Comment: Check if the package `TableARepository` resides in is being scanned.

Answer (score -1):

add the annotation `@Repository`

```
@Repository
public interface TableARepository extends CrudRepository<TableA, Long>{
    @Query(value = "SELECT r FROM TableA r  WHERE r.Id = :Id", nativeQuery = true)
    public Rater getTableAById(@Param("Id") Long Id);
}
```

Comment: Tried it, did not work, same error.

Comment: `@Repository` does effectively nothing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691697/using-repository-annotation-when-implementing-jparepostiory-in-spring