# When to use service or component in spring?

Tags: java, spring, system-design

When to use service or component in spring?

For example, is a module responsible for sending email or common business logic a "service" or a "component"?
and what's the difference?

Is a service able to call the other services? 
Is there any transaction problem? or a service should call the components only?

Someone told me that a service should never call the other services and should only call the components instead, which means Controller->Service->Component->DAO, but I found many people share the concept of Controller->Service->DAO with no component.

Is there any system design criteria about this topic in Spring?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In order to "configure" Spring so it can provide you with the instances of the classes you need, you are supposed to tell Spring *what* objects are involved and *how* they are built. To do this you can use an xml configuration file or through annotations

In case you take the annotation approach (IMHO a much better and simpler one) you can use `@Component` to annotate the class. This is like telling Spring: "Hey! I want you to know that you may need an instance of this class. Maybe because I request it, maybe because something I requested needs it". So annotating a class with `@Component` just let Spring know that it exists

There are other annotations that do the same:

- `@Controller` (and `@RestController`)
- `@Service`
- `@Repository`

They all inform Spring that the class is involved in the DI context. **But** they also have semantic meaning:

- `@Controller` = `@Component` belonging to Presentation Layer
- `@Service` = `@Component` belonging to Service/Use Case Layer
- `@Repository` = `@Component` belonging to Persistence Layer

You can find more info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in)

> Should a service be able to call the other services?

I don't see any problem with that. If any of your services requires to do some actions that are already performed by other you surely want to avoid code duplication. As long as you respect the architecture layers dependency (never going up) you'll be fine.

About this you can check [this article](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) about Clean Architecture

Answer (score 5):

`@Component` is generic for other stereotypes.
So you can replace 
 `@Repository, @Service, @Controller`  with `@Component` and nothing will change. But for better readability you should use `@Repository, @Service, @Controller`

Comment: not exactly true. `@Repository` adds exception handling specific to databases. and yes other annotations adds nothing but it is matter of time. There could be additions in future.

Comment: Little incorrect. @ Controller and @ Repository provide additional functionality to the class so we can't interchange these with @ Component. And Spring may add extra features to @ Service in future so you will miss those features if you use @ Component.