# Spring Boot can't find DataSource for JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, camunda

I have a Spring Boot application that happens to use Camunda for BPMN.  Everything works fine.  I have the Hikairi DBPool and the datasource properties in my application.properties file.  Every thing runs fine,  and workflows work etc...

I now want to access my DB via JdbcTemplate,  using the same DataSource, as all the tables are on the same DB.  I add this class:

```
@Component
public class MyDao extends JdbcDaoSupport {

  public MyRow getMyRowById(int id) {
    String sql = "select * from MyTable where id = ?";
    try {
        MyRow myRow = (MyRow)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[] { id }, new MyRowMapper());
        return myRow;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

And I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
```

How is that possible when I know it's there.  I see in the logs that Hikari is using it and adding itself as the DataSource for pooling.  If I simply remove the @Component and it at least deploys,  but as you would think,  it throws a null pointer at the getJdbcTemplate() call.

Is there an annotation I am missing to get this to autowire correctly and expose the DataSource to my JdbcTemplate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should annotate your `MyDao` with the `@Repository` annotation and not with just the `@Component` one. For this reason, please take a moment to read [What's the difference between @Component, @Repository & @Service annotations in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in).

Second, looking at your exception, seems you are missing the injection of the jdbcTemplate/datasource in the `MyDao`. For this point, if you are working with the datasource itself and not with the `JdbcTemplate`, you can inject the datasource as following:

```
@Autowired
public void setDs(DataSource dataSource) {
     setDataSource(dataSource);
}
```

However, if you are using the `JdbcTemplate`, you can add a setter injection inside you `MyDao` as following:

```
@Autowired
public void setJt(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
     setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
}
```