# What is a spring service annotation?

Tags: spring

I understand that `@Service` is used to mark a class as a business logic class. Why is it useful for spring? I can already use `@Component` to mark a class as a bean. I understand that `@Service` is more specific than `@Component`, but how?

Comment: we can use `@Component` but I think `@Service` specifies intent better. both works.

Comment: I do not understand if @Service is handled differently

Comment: See: [What's the difference between Component, Repository & Service annotations in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

@Service, @Controller, @Repository = {@Component + some more special functionality}

Click the below link for more details

[What's the difference between @Component, @Repository & @Service annotations in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in)

> The @Component annotation marks a java class as a bean so the
>   component-scanning mechanism of spring can pick it up and pull it into
>   the application context. The @Service annotation is also a
>   specialization of the component annotation. It doesn’t currently
>   provide any additional behavior over the @Component annotation, but
>   it’s a good idea to use @Service over @Component in service-layer
>   classes because it specifies intent better. Additionally, tool support
>   and additional behavior might rely on it in the future.

Answer (score 37):

Consider `@Component` annotation as a *Swiss Knife*.  It can act as cutting knife, as an opener, as a scissor, etc.

[image: Component]

Similarly, your Component can act as a Repository, as Business Logic class or as a controller.

Now, `@Service` is a just one of the versions of `@Component`, say a knife.

Spring process `@Service` similar to `@Component`, since `@Service` interface itself is annotated with `@Component`.

From Spring docs.:

> ```
> @Target(value=TYPE)
> @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
> @Documented
> @Component
> public @interface Service
> ```
>
> Indicates that an annotated class is a "Service" (e.g. a business
>   service facade).

*Why to differentiate both of them?*

To apply the basic rule of programming: **Your code should be easily readable.**

Yes, you can use `@Component` annotation everywhere and it will work fine but for the better understanding of the code, it is preferred to use the respective special types of annotations like `@Service` in our case.

The other benefit is ease of debugging. Once you know the error, you need not hope from one component class to another, checking it time whether that class is service, repository or controller.

Comment: Similarly or identically?

Comment: Exactly the way it processes `@Component`.

Comment: Worth asking: Are Services implicitly `@Autowired`? I see a tutorial [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method) that it is not autowired but expected to work

Answer (score 6):

The @Service annotation is a specialization of the component annotation. It doesn’t currently provide any additional behavior over the @Component annotation, but it’s a good idea to use @Service over @Component in service-layer classes because it specifies intent better. Additionally, tool support and additional behavior might rely on it in the future.