# When should I use @Component instead of @Service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, software-quality

I've already read about each Spring annotation in [What's the difference between @Component, @Repository & @Service annotations in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in)

I know that `@Component` and `@Service` do almost the same inside the Spring Framework. The difference it's bounded to it's usage, so I just use `@Service` into the *service layer* where I access my *repositories*.

I want to know what's the better way to choose `@Component` instead of `@Service`. Note that I'm using `@Component` now for a factory I've created, because the factory don't need to deal with repositories.

Comment: Ultimately it doesn't matter much, just use what seems logical to you. Sometimes I use @Service on classes that don't use repositories, and only use other services.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keep in mind that these are Spring stereotypes, and should be applied as stereotypes or assumptions around one's code are usually applied.

- If your component is a generic component, not really living at the service layer, or is accessible but *could* hold state, then use `@Component`.
- If your component is a specific service, living at the service layer, or is accessible and does *not* inherently hold state, use `@Service`.

Spring sees both of these ultimately as `@Component`s.

Comment: Why the association of Component with statefulness (and vice versa)?