# Repository object not being Autowired in Service class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch-5

I am having a `Repository` through which I'm getting data from **Elasticsearch**. It is working correctly when I send a `GEt` request.
I need that data from **Elasticsearch** without sending a `GET` request for which I've written a `Service` and annotated that repository in `Service` class using `@Autowired`.
**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface RecipeDtoRepository extends 
ElasticsearchRepository<RecipeDto, Integer> {}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/repo")
public class RecipeRepoController {
@Autowired
public RecipeDtoRepository recipeDtoRepository;

@GetMapping("/all")
public String getRecipes() {
    List<RecipeDto> recipe_list = new ArrayList<>();
    recipeDtoRepository.findAll().forEach(recipe_list::add);
    return recipe_list.toString();
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
@Component
public class ClusterService implements ApplicationContextAware {
  @Autowired
public RecipeDtoRepository recipeDtoRepository;
List<RecipeDto> recipe_list = new ArrayList<>();
   new ClusterService(). applicationContext.getBean(RecipeRepoController.class).recipeDtoRepository.findAll().forEach(recipe_list::add);
}
@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext 
applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}
```

**Problem**
when calling the method in controller using `GET` request, it is working fine but when I call it using `Service` class, it is throwing `NullPointerException` which it shouldn't be according to my knowledge. I read an article where it was suggested to get the `Bean` in `Service` class which you can see I've done using `ApplicationContext` but it is throwing that exception. I've tried it without using `ApplicationContext` and it throws `NullPointerException` in that case too. I'm working over it for the last two days and unable to find a solution.

```
@Service
@Configurable
public class ClusterService {
@Autowired
public  RecipeDtoRepository recipeDtoRepository;

private  String getRecipes() {
    List<RecipeDto> recipe_list = new ArrayList<>();
    recipeDtoRepository.findAll().forEach(recipe_list::add);
    return recipe_list.toString();
}


public static void main(String[] a) {

    ClusterService clusterService = new ClusterService();
    clusterService.getRecipes();

}}
```

Comment: You appear to be using `new ClusterService()` which would create the `ClusterService` outside of Spring.

Comment: @AshleyFrieze what am I supposed to do. I've to call Repository in **ClusterService** class and fetch data in it

Comment: I presume you're trying to get your controller to use the service. So Autowire the service into the controller. Wherever you need a Spring Bean you need to get Spring to provide it to your calling code.

You should not be using the application context directly, instead, you let Spring build all your beans and you express how they need each other.

Comment: @Jamshaid replace `new ClusterService(). applicationContext` with `context` and `@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;`

Comment: `   new ClusterService(). applicationContext.getBean ... ` this line in class context does not even compile. Please take time to post your example in a form that at least compiles. On top of that: you probably don't need ApplicationContextAware to inject a bean, can you show us your attempt with that approach?

Comment: @PasupathiRajamanickam I'm in main() and need it there. As I've tried, we can't apply **Autowired** on static fields and by creating a new object, it'll again leave spring

Comment: @AshleyFrieze I've posted the controller in order to show how code is there and is in working form.  I'm not calling Service in controller

Comment: Super confused, can you format your code add all the static stuff you're talking about?

Comment: @Lesiak I didn't get your point. would you please elaborate it more. Thans

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Comment: @PasupathiRajamanickam please have a look at the question again

Comment: @Jamshaid how you are binding the service in controller, also can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @Jamshaid i know you are trying to test but please don't do ClusterService clusterService = new ClusterService(); if you have used stereotype annotation

Comment: @triples13 I'm not using service in controller.

Comment: @Jamshaid so you are trying to call the service using main method?

Comment: Yeah/. You're right . I'm calling it using main. Please see the question again. Have a look at edit 1

Comment: @Jamshaid Why do you have a main method in the middle of spring bean class? There is no such thing exist. You should have only one main that initialize SpringbootApplication. Spring wont work with main in middle of bean.

Comment: You should autowire your service class in controller and call method inside service class that's how things works. If you would like to persist something in memory, you should consider using `@PostConstruct` and utilize the member list

Comment: @PasupathiRajamanickam can you please provide a reference link for your 2nd last comment. Thanks

Comment: @Jamshaid answered please check if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Remove the contextAware and dont call the instance of repository from the controller since you have injected it yet
just do this

```
public void addThings(){
this.recipeDtoRepository.findAll().forEach(recipe_list::add)
}
```

Comment: How am i supposed to do that?

Comment: wait, just remove the new Cluster.... all line and create a method inside yopu put your behaviour like

Comment: as I'm accessing it in main() , it'll ask me to access it using an object which will obviously be created using new and that won't work again as we can't apply @Autowired on static fields

Comment: dont use the controller to access the repository, you have injected it yet

Comment: Why do you access it from main?

Comment: can you give me all the context so i can see?

Comment: As I need to do it by directly running this class. It is performing a bit separate task from the original application

Comment: so call the method from the class, but you don't need to access the instance of the repository defined in the controller, you have it

Comment: by all the context you mean repository class and content of the main method?

Comment: please have a look at the quesion. I've just edited it

Comment: also remove @ Component from your ClusterService as @ Service is an @ Component

Comment: Now having just @Service and same exception

Comment: ok i understand  in the main method you create an instance of the spring context ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(YourConfigurationClass.class); next you get the instance of clusterService by doing Clusterservice service =  context.getBean(ClusterService.class);

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(YourConfigurationClass.class);
        Clusterservice service = context.getBean(ClusterService.class);
        clusterService.getRecipes(); 

    }

Comment: which one is the configuration class?

Comment: your configuration class, usually it's annotated with @Configuration

Comment: and remove @@Configurable from the ClusterService

Comment: I've a configuration class defined for elasticsearch configuration but it isn't accepting that

Comment: No qualifying bean of type 'com.techno.homes.search.service.ClusterService' available

Comment: did your configuration class scan the package of Clusterservice?

Comment: are you using spring boot?

Comment: yeah. I'm using spring boot

Comment: ok so just remove the parameter of annotation...context and replace it by ApplicationContext conntext= new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

Comment: Config class doesn't scan anything. It just has @ Configuration

Comment: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5d47c63f has not been refreshed yet
this error

Comment: call context.refresh() before;it seems to scan the package of the Config class, is it in the same package as the clusterService?

Comment: context.refresh isn't available.

Comment: It isn't in the same packge.

Answer (score 1):

if you have annotated your class using stereotype annotation and you are trying to get bean in main class try this

```
     ApplicationContext context= 
           SpringApplication.run(Main.class,args);
                ClusterService clusterService=context.getBean(ClusterService.class);
clusterService.getRecipes();
```

Comment: @Jamshaid please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52267478/should-i-never-use-new-keyword-on-a-spring-boot-project

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that OP wants to persist a list and use it through out the lifecycle. Here is my recommendation

```
@Service
public class ClusterService {
    @Autowired
    public RecipeDtoRepository recipeDtoRepository;

    private List<RecipeDto> recipeList = null;

    @PostContruct
    public void setup() {
       recipeList = new ArrayList<>();
       recipeDtoRepository.findAll().forEach(recipeList::add);
    }

    public getReceipeList() {
      return recipeList;
    }

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/repo")
public class RecipeRepoController {
    @Autowired
    ClusterService clusterService

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public String getRecipes() {
        return clusterService.getReceipeList().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've this thing already in working format as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: I was trying to access the data using the new main method, which you said isn't true. Can you please give me a reference link for that.

Comment: It is impossible to use `public static void main` and make spring dependency work. It's like you want orange from apple tree :)

Comment: If you want something from spring but you don't need any controller, you should probably use spring-batch https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-spring-batch