# SpringBootApplication scanBasePackages is not reading subpackages

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a common library published on nexus that has package id

```
x.xx.common
```

it contains sub packages of common feign clients proxy interfaces

The project that uses this library has package id.

```
x.xx.account 
x.xx.device
```

each of these projects has its application class in the root

```
x.xx.account.AppClass
x.xx.device.AppClass
```

each of these class has

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"x.xx"})
```

for some reason both projects don't see any of the proxy interfaces under subpackages

```
x.xx.common.proxy
x.xx.common.configuration
```

I tried moved the proxy interfaces directly under main package

```
x.xx.common
```

but it also failed

Parameter 0 of constructor in x.xx.common.service.impl.AuditServiceImpl required a bean of type 'x.xx.common.LogProxy' that could not be found.

that error is given for every interface proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, apparently the AppClass `@EnableFeignClients` need to have the base class added to it as well.

So for anyone that has the same problem my `AppClass` now has the following annotation

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"x.xx"})
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages= {"x.xx"})
public class AppClass {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add annotation to your sub packages class which you want to be scanned. Add the annotations like `@Component`, `@Service` or `@Repository` respectively to the class respectively.
For the annotation:
`@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"x.xx"})`

Suppose there is a class named `Abc` in the subpackage `x.xx`, so add the annotation @Component to the class.

`@Component
 class Abc{}`

This will help to read the sub packages class.

To know more about the difference between the above mention annotations: [What's the difference between @Component, @Repository & @Service annotations in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in)