# What Spring annotations can we use in Hybris commerce project?

Tags: spring, sap-commerce-cloud, spring-annotations

I was reading about Spring core module and came across Spring annotations that I did not see till now in the Hybris project:

@Component,@Qualifier

Are these used in Hybris projects?

Comment: what do you mean by Hybris projects?

Comment: I mean when we are writing some code for performing some functionality

Answer (score 0):

Hybris 6.6 uses Spring 4.3. The usual annotations like @Autowired, @Required, @Controller, and many others should work.

If you have access to Hybris Help, have a look at "Spring Framework in SAP Commerce": https://help.hybris.com/6.6.0/hcd/8c63621986691014a7e0a18695d7d410.html

There is:

- Dependency Injection
- Interface-Driven Design
- Beans (and aliasing)
- Spring Profiles
- Spring MVC
- Spring Integration
- etc

Comment: Thanks a lot.However I have not seen Component and Qualifier annotations.Are they supported?

Comment: @Rachit I've seen Qualifier used in Hybris' JUnit codes, and Component used in validators.

Comment: Normally do you suggest using it in a normal scenario when you call Facade from your controller and go to the DAO later to retrieve something ?

Comment: As @Mafick mentioned, it depends on you. You can use either XML configuration or annotations (as long component scanning is enabled). In practice, you will most likely be using both.

Answer (score 0):

Hybris uses both. Annotation Injection and XML Injection. You can also use both. I recommend you, to define a clear strategy when you use which one.

For example:

```
Controller - Annotation Injection
Facade - XML Injection
Service - XML Injection
```

To your point, which kind of Annotation you should use, have a look here:
[What's the difference between @Component, @Repository & @Service annotations in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in)

In common said, there is not really a different. It's just nice to use the correct Annotation for the correct class.