# @Service vs @Component in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, annotations

I understand the difference between @Component and @Controller, @Component and @Repository, but was not able to find what additional feature we get in @Service as compared to @Component.

Comment: Answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in

Answer (score 12):

[image]

We can directly use `@Component` for each and every bean, but for better understanding and maintainability of a large application, we use `@Controller, @Service, @Repository`.

```
@Component: generic stereotype for any Spring-managed component 
@Service: stereotype for service layer
```

---

**@Component**

Definitions of @Controller, @Service and @Repository annotations which tells that @Service is a special type of @Component. Special type annotations are also scanned because they themselves are annotated with `@Component` annotation, which means they are also `@Component`s. If we define our own custom annotation and annotate it with `@Component`, it will also get scanned with `<context:component-scan>`

```
@Component
public @interface Service {
    ….
}

@Component
public @interface Repository {
    ….
}

@Component
public @interface Controller {
    …
}
```

**@Service**

`@Service` beans hold the business logic and call methods in the repository layer.