# Springboot controller issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Problem with web starter project from spring initializer. Springboot 2.2.0

I just created a `spring boot 2.2.0` project from spring initializer website with web starter dependency. The application works fine if I user `@RestController` annotation and send request from postman but when I use `@Controller` annotation and try to load the hello.html page which is in /resources/templates directory it throws **null or white label errors.** It's weird the package structure is perfect but it's not working.

I could not find any answer thread so far for this issue.

Comment: please show the code

Answer (score 1):

Possible Issue:

When you use `@Controller` add `@ResponseBody`
`@ResponseBody` is required when we use `@Controller`. `@RestController` is a special  version of `@Controller` in which `@ResponseBody` is active by default

**[@Controller vs @RestController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in/56882597#56882597)**

---

with *@Controller*

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping(value= "/hello")
    public @ResponseBody String sayHello()
    {   
        retrun "Hello";
    }
}
```

---

with *@RestContoller*

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping(value= "/hello")
    public String sayHello()
    {   
        retrun "Hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@RestController : If it is a @RestController it just return the value whatever we given in return statement. 
For eg:

HomeController.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value="/")
public String index() {
   return "home";
}
}
```

The output is:  home

It just only returns the return statement

@Controller : The @Controller annotation is returns the view page (resource/template/home.html). For Eg:

HomeController.java

```
 package com.example.demo;

 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

 @Controller
 public class HomeController {

 @RequestMapping(value="/")
 public String index() {
    return "home";
 }
 }
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <img alt="Image" src="/images/barbie.jpg">
 </body>
</html>
```

The output: It display home.html page

[image]

Comment: What about view resolver, it won’t work without it.

Comment: It's a simple controller trying to render the corresponding view. I think some how the application is not able to find the corresponding page in the project directory. Could you provide how the view is searched in spring application?

Comment: No html files are loaded which are in resources folder. Its weird!

Comment: I done this using spring boot - gradle application. In Spring boot  we can also use html file.

Answer (score 0):

Is thymeleaf dependency added to your project??

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply updating the maven dependency resolved the issue. Thank you guys for your response.