# Can I| use @Repository for DAO layer in spring boot

Tags: spring

Can we use `@Repository` for DAO layer in spring boot ?

What is the difference between `@Component` and `@Repository` ?
Which one should we use for DAO layer in Spring boot ?

Comment: Hello Pavan  the answer is YES.
Please visit this link for futher information : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in

Answer (score 1):

`@Repository` is a specialization of `@Component` whose purpose is to handle DAO. So the answer is yes.

`@Repository` *javadoc* states :

> Indicates that an annotated class is a "Repository", originally defined by Domain-Driven Design (Evans, 2003) as "a mechanism for encapsulating storage, retrieval, and search behavior which emulates a collection of objects".
>   **Teams implementing traditional Java EE patterns such as "Data Access Object" may also apply this stereotype to DAO classes**, though care should be taken to understand the distinction between Data Access Object and DDD-style repositories before doing so. This annotation is a general-purpose stereotype and individual teams may narrow their semantics and use as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

@Repository is an annotation marker. No difference between @Component and @Repository, spring already can create bean instance from your interface if you extends JpaRepository or other spring repository interfaces

For example:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, BigInteger> {

    User findByUsernameOrEmail(String username, String email);
}
```

For more information please follow the [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-stereotype-annotations)