# Getting resource not found when try to return html page from controller

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am unable to render html page in springboot.
Here is code...

```
@RestController
    public class ProductController {
        @Autowired
        ProductService service;
    
        @InitBinder
        public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            dateFormat.setLenient(false);
            webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
        }
        
        @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" })
        public ModelAndView home() {
            System.out.println("sdasasas");
            return new ModelAndView("home");
        }
```

but whenever i hit http://localhost:8080/home it shows following logs

```
-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/signed-exchange;v=b3, application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8]
2019-07-31 16:05:25.354 DEBUG 14850 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'home', model {}
2019-07-31 16:05:25.354 DEBUG 14850 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/html/home.html]
2019-07-31 16:05:25.354 DEBUG 14850 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/WEB-INF/html/home.html", parameters={}
2019-07-31 16:05:25.356 DEBUG 14850 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/","/"]
2019-07-31 16:05:25.356  WARN 14850 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/html/home.html]
2019-07-31 16:05:25.356 DEBUG 14850 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2019-07-31 16:05:25.357 DEBUG 14850 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404
2019-07-31 16:05:25.357 DEBUG 14850 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2019-07-31 16:05:25.357 DEBUG 14850 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2019-07-31 16:05:25.357 DEBUG 14850 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid `@RestController` for *MVC Based Application* which has to return a view. It is mainly used for REST APIs. While *`@Controller` can return a view*

*More On `@RestController`*:

[image]

- This annotation is a specialized version of `@Controller` which adds
  `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` annotation automatically. so we do not have to add `@ResponseBody` to our mapping methods. That means
  `@ResponseBody` is default active.
- If you use `@RestController` you cannot return a view (By using
  `Viewresolver` in Spring/Spring-Boot)
- `@RestController` also converts the response to `JSON/XML automatically` as `@ResponseBody` makes the returned objects to something that could be in the body, `e.g. JSON or XML`

**[Controller vs RestController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56882597/10961238)**

---

```
@RestController
    public class ProductController {
        @Autowired
        ProductService service;

        @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" })
        public @ResponseBody ModelAndView home() {
            System.out.println("sdasasas");
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
            modelAndView.setViewName("home");
            return modelAndView;
        }
}
```

Project Structure
[image]

No need to specify `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/html/ spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html`

Also, make sure you don't have any additional class with `@EnableWebMvc` annotation. This can mess up the *spring-boot autoconfiguration.*

Comment: I have tried @Controller but that also doesn't worked.

Comment: Hello @Sahil, Can you update the question with new error

Comment: @Sahil Also add `@ResponseBody` as I have added in answer and let me know how its work

Comment: here i debug log after using above options.....                                    2019-07-31 18:57:38.785  WARN 32127 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/html/home.html]
2019-07-31 18:57:38.786 DEBUG 32127 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2019-07-31 18:57:38.786 DEBUG 32127 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404

Comment: @Sahil After adding ResponseBody are you getting this? and where you have kept home.html file

Comment: Yes @Patel. I have placed home.html under webapp/WEB-INF/html. and in application.properties here is configured prefix path----spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/html/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html

Comment: Hello @Sahil can you add your project structure

Comment: @Sahil Have you manually created WEB-INF as there is no default WEB-INF is ther e for Spring Boot

Comment: I have checked using above project structure also but that also doen't worked. Can you please share your email or something so that i can share project with you. I am still getting resource not found.

Comment: Hi @patel i have shared the project with you. Please check and thnx for your assistance.

Comment: @Sahil 403, please provide the access

Answer (score 2):

You should always use `@Controller` Annotation while using Spring MVC.
`@RestController` is different from `@Controller`.

`@Controller` returns a view, used in MVC applications,

While `@RestController` returns a response(Mostly Json), it converts your your java object to Json by using Jackson jar, and these are used for api's.

Comment: But i am returning ModelAndView from @RestController. And that can be return from restcontroller.

Comment: I have tried @Controller but that also doesn't worked.

Comment: show where you have written the view resolver and configurations in properties file

Answer (score 1):

@RestController is not meant to be used to return views to be resolved. It is supposed to return data which will be written to the body of the response

```
        @RestController     //change it to @Controller
        public class ProductController {
        @Autowired
        ProductService service;
```

This difference between @Controller and the @RestController annotation is that @Controller is to create a Map of model object and find a view but the @RestController simply returns the object and object data is directly written into HTTP response as JSON or XML.

Comment: hi @Rajendra Gupta thnx for quick response. i have tried this also but doesn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are returning a view page like .jsp from the controller, and it's throwing an error saying cannot locate resource .jsp or 404 not found, then try adding these dependencies to your pom file, it worked for me.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your project structure.
The class where you are calling SpringApplication.run(XXX.class, args), hierarchy wise should be on top, and then other classes where you are using @RestController.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).