# Slight Difference between @RestController & @Component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-annotations

Although every page on internet says that @RestController is a specification of @Component.I dont know whether it has to be related with DispatcherServlet. But when I try below code by switching between @RestController & @Component, I don't see same behaviour :

First I tried with @RestController:

```
@RestComponent
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/testController", method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void testController() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

}
```

I got below output in Console:

> Hello

Second I tried with @Component + @ResponseBody:

```
@Component
@ResponseBody
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/testController", method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void testController() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

I got an error on postman:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1570998345860,
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
    "path": "/testController"
}
```

If both annotations are same, then why is there a difference in output ??

Below is the Source code for @RestController & @Controller , which shows that both @RestController & @Controller are specification of @Component:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Controller
@ResponseBody
public @interface RestController {

}


@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface Controller {
}
```

Maybe it has to be related with DispatcherServlet. It might be possible that Dispatcher Servlet only check for URL in @RestController annotated classes.

Comment: I don't know how you missed this from doc `Indicates that an annotated class is a "Controller" (e.g. a web controller).` https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html

Answer (score 3):

@Controller is user in traditional controller and @RestController annotation was introduced to simplify the creation of RESTful web services. **It's a convenience annotation that combines @Controller and @ResponseBody**

@Controller annotation is simply a specialized of the @Component class and allows implementation classes to be autodetect through the classpath scanning.

@Controller is typically used in combination with a @RequestMapping annotation used on request handling methods.

The request handling method is annotated with @ResponseBody. This annotation enables automatic serialization of the return object into the HttpResponse.

@RestController is a specialized version of the controller. It includes the @Controller and @ResponseBody annotations and as a result, simplifies the controller implementation.

The controller is annotated with the @RestController annotation, therefore the @ResponseBody isn't required.

Every request handling method of the controller class automatically serializes return objects into HttpResponse.
see here in detail : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller

Answer (score 2):

Just because `@RestController` is a `@Component` does not mean you can achieve the same functionality by switching to the broader one `@Component`. Even with the addition of `@ResponseBody`, you don't achieve equivalent functionality (as expressed through the Request Method `POST` not being supported).

Replace `@Component` with `@Controller`, because a `@RestController` has the exact same functionality as a `@Controller` + `@ResponseBody`. You can also see this in the meta-annotations of `@RestController`, you see it is meta-annotated with `@Controller` instead of just `@Component`. In turn, `@Controller` is meta-annotated with `@Component`.

Comment: RestController = Controller (=Component) + ResponseBody, So effectively RestController = Component + ResponseBody

Comment: @ASharma7 Your logic is faulty because while a `@RestController` IS a `@Component` plus `@ResponseBody`, it has extended functionality that a `@Component` + `@ResponseBody` does not offer. It's like saying a Tesla is a car, and while that is true, a Tesla has more functionality than a normal car that you might need. In order to get that extended functionality here (namely supporting HTTP request methods like `POST`, you need to have the `@Controller` + `@ResponseBody`, not `@Component` + `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: @ASharma7 you seem to assume that `@Controller` is equivalent to `@Component`. That is false.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I am NOT ASSUMING. I am showing the source code of Controller. Its nothing more than Component in source code.

Comment: @ASharma7 again, you seem to assume that just because the annotation is only meta annotated there is nothing else going on. This is false. `@Controller` specifically demarcates a controller in the MVC framework.

Answer (score 1):

The `@Controller` , `@RestController` , `@Service` etc are all annotations that are meta-annotated with the `@Component` annotation. All these annotations are essentially specializations of the `@Component` annotation for specific use cases.
 The `@Component` annotation is generally used to register a Spring bean.

The `@Controller` annotation even though it is annotated with `@Component` internally , it provides a different functionality altogether.By annotating a class with this annotation we are essentially telling spring to scan this class for `@RequestMapping` annotation to register beans for request mapping. This does not happen when you just use the `@Component` annotation.

When the spring application starts up, the `DispatcherServlet` will enable the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` (which is a handler mapping which looks for `@RequestMapping` annotations on `@Controller`s). So when a request reaches the dispatcher servlet it gives it to the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` which resolves the uri to a controller method bean.For more information read : [`DispatcherServlet`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/html/ch15s02.html), [Updated Doc Spring 5.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-controller) [`HandlerMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/html/ch15s04.html)

Note :
In older versions of spring `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`  is enabled for this by spring.

So in summary :

- `@Component` is a generic stereotype for any Spring-managed component
  or bean.
- `@Repository` is a stereotype for the persistence layer.
- `@Service` is a stereotype for the service layer.
- `@Controller` is a stereotype for the presentation layer (spring-MVC).

[Spring [Doc][4]](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-classpath-scanning).

> The `@Controller` annotation indicates that a particular class serves
>   the role of a controller.
>
> The basic purpose of the `@Controller` annotation is to act as a
>   stereotype for the annotated class, indicating its role. The
>   dispatcher will scan such annotated classes for mapped methods,
>   detecting `@RequestMapping` annotations (see the next section).
>
> Annotated controller beans may be defined explicitly, using a standard
>   Spring bean definition in the dispatcher's context. However, the
>   `@Controller` stereotype also allows for autodetection, aligned with
>   Spring 2.5's general support for detecting component classes in the
>   classpath and auto-registering bean definitions for them.

Similar post : [What's the difference between @Component, @Repository & @Service annotations in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in)

Comment: I understand that. This is why i am getting status = 405. I also understand that official documentation says @Controller provides something special that it starts behaving like webcontroller. But if some functionality comes into picture, there must be source code behind that. My ask is the source code, which gives that Controller that special behaviour. I am asking this because I had been asked in one of interview

Comment: @ASharma7Please read: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/html/ch15s02.html and also on how handler mapping maps a request uri to a controller https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/html/ch15s04.html

Comment: @ASharma7I have updated the answer hope this clears things up for you.

Comment: The `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` doesn't exists anymore its successor `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` should be used instead. You are also linking to old (read ancient) documentation, you want to use the current one (Spring 5.2 not 3.0).

Answer (score 0):

You should not get the same behaviour because @Component is more generic. It only registers your class as a Spring Managed Bean. However, @RestController not only registers your class as a managed bean, it further registers it as an entry point for HTTP calls to the specified URL path. Same goes for other Layer specific annotations like @Repository, @Configuration e.t.c