# Cross Origin request gets blocked even after annotating the controller with @CrossOrigin(origins="*")?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I've a SpringBoot Controller as follows

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="*")
public class FormController {
      @PostMapping(path="/basicForm")
 public String postResponseController(
              @RequestBody FormDomain loginForm) {
        System.err.println("basic form method called");
         return "file transfer completed successfully";
     }
}
```

I've annotated the controller with `@CrossOrigin(origins="*")` to enable CORS.
Here is my FormDomain Class

```
public class FormDomain {
     private MultipartFile fileInput;

    public MultipartFile getFileInput() {
        return fileInput;
    }

    public void setFileInput(MultipartFile fileInput) {
        this.fileInput = fileInput;
    }
    }
```

And the angular script calling the controller method

```
 onClickSubmit(data) {
        this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/basicForm", data).subscribe( (ob)=>(console.log(ob)));
      }
```

Eventhough I've annotated the controller to enable CORS I get following error in browser console

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/basicForm' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Add `@RestController` in `FormController `

Comment: Use the developer tools in a browser and check if the headers are sent or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `@RestController` in `FormController`

`@Controller` a specialization of the `@Component` class and allows implementation classes to be autodetected through the classpath scanning. while `@RestController` is a specialization of the `@Controller` which eliminates the need for `@ResponseBody`. You can refer [@Controller, RestController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56882597/10961238)