# Not able to get response with @Controller, while @RestController works fine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to map the URL `/function/hash` in my project to a specific HTML page `html/hashcode.html`. This is a spring boot project without using thymeleaf.

This is my code:

```java
// package ...;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class FunctionController {
    @RequestMapping("/function/hash")
    public String hashPage(Model m) {
        return "html/hashcode.html";
    }
}
```

The above code returns a 404 when I try to access `localhost:8080/function/hash`.

I also tried

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/function")
public class FunctionController {
    @RequestMapping("/hash")
    public String hashPage(Model m) {
        return "html/hashcode.html";
    }
}
```

which also yields a 404 when I go to `localhost:8080/function/hash`.

Directly using `@RequestMapping("/hash")` to map the page to `/hash` works, in case you wonder if the return value of the function is incorrect.

I also find that using multiple layer url like `@RequestMapping("/api/test")` is working in `@RestController` classes, but somehow it doesn't work in this `@Controller` class above.

Comment: Set `logging.level.org.springframework.web` to DEBUG and you'll get a list of all of the controller mappings at startup. Examine the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `"/html/hashcode.html"`(prefix `/`), 
and create `<project-root>/src/main/resources/static/html/hashcode.html`

```
@Controller
public class FunctionController {
    @RequestMapping("/function/hash")
    public String hashPage(final Model m) {
        return "/html/hashcode.html";
    }
}
```

---

When return `"html/hashcode.html"`:

```
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/function/html/hashcode.html", parameters={}
```

On the other hand, when return `"/html/hashcode.html"`:

```
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/html/hashcode.html", parameters={}
```

Comment: Yes it worked! Turns out adding a prefix ```/``` before the ```html/hashcode.html``` is the correct answer. For other ```@RequestMapping```s in my project, having no ```/``` before ```html/some-other-page.html``` works fine when the link mapped to the file has no multiple layers (e.g. ```/main```, or ```/test```), which is so weird. Why would a ```/``` here make the difference?

Answer (score 0):

use `path` in request mapping.

Ex:

`@RequestMapping(path="/hash")`

Comment: I tried both ```@RequestMapping(path="/function/hash")``` and using double annotation ```@RequestMapping(path="/function")``` plus ```@RequestMapping(path="/hash")```, but all of them yield 404

Comment: It should work. Is it possible for you to share the code in GitHub ?

Answer (score 0):

`@RestController` is combination of `@Controller + @ResponseBody`. While using `@Controller` we have to add the `@ResponseBody` with our methods. You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56882597/10961238)

```
@Controller
public class MappingController {

    @RequestMapping("/endpoint1") //returns 404
    public String endPoint1() {
        return "Hello endpoint1";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/endpoint2") //works well because of @ResponseBody
    public @ResponseBody String endPoint2() {
        return "Hello endpoint2";
    }
}
```

---

Add `@ResponseBody` and these both should work fine

```
@Controller
public class FunctionController {
    @RequestMapping("/function/hash")
    public @ResponseBody String hashPage(Model m) {
        return "html/hashcode.html";
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/function")
public class FunctionController {
    @RequestMapping("/hash")
    public @ResponseBody String hashPage(Model m) {
        return "html/hashcode.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: Here I am trying to map this link ```/function/hash``` to an existing page in my project, namely ```html/hashcode.html```. Adding ```@ResponseBody``` will make this act as a ```@RestController``` which returns only a string containing ```"html/hashcode.html"```, which is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

add @ResponseBody annotation, The @Controller is a common annotation which is used to mark a class as Spring MVC Controller while the @RestController is a special controller used in RESTFul web services and the equivalent of @Controller + @ResponseBody

if u add @ResponseBody  it will work. use below code

```
// package ...;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class FunctionController {

    @RequestMapping("/function/hash")
    public @ResponseBody String hashPage(Model m) {
        return "html/hashcode.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: Here I am trying to map this link ```/function/hash``` to an existing page in my project, namely ```html/hashcode.html```. Adding ```@ResponseBody``` will make this act as a ```@RestController``` which returns only a string containing ```"html/hashcode.html"```, which is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If the html files are static resources, consider [the static content support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) in Spring Boot.

Configure a `spring.resources.static-locations` to specify the resource localtions.

```
spring.resources.static-locations=file:/opt/files/,classpath:/static-files
```

And set the mapping pattern if you do not want to map it the root path.

```
pring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/content/**
```

(Or `spring.webflux.static-path-pattern` for Spring webflux application)

Now you can view the resources via http://localhost:8080/content/some.html

Comment: Here I am trying to avoid accessing the file directly and use a mapped link instead because of clarification reasons, so I used a ```@RequestMapping``` instead