# Spring Boot did not Autowiring

Tags: spring-boot, autowired

Can someone tell me please what I'm doing wrong, I'm trying to develop a little application but I just simply can't `Autowire` a class in the controller, I have been researching and I Know that for `Autowire` works, my class must be in a child package of my `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, or I should specify in `@ComponentScan` annotation the package of my class, but no matters what I do I still getting the same error:

[image]

This is my project structure:

[image]

```
package net.spring.auditoria;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;T
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AuditoriaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuditoriaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
package net.spring.auditoria.bll;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class AuditoriaController {

    @Autowired
    private AuditoriaManagement am;
    
    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuditoriaController.class);
    
    @GetMapping("/auditar")
    public String auditar() {
        LOGGER.info("auditar()");
        return "main";
    }
    
}
```

https://github.com/jlpm-mex/auditoria

Answer (score 3):

Because `AuditoriaManagement` is not a Spring bean or component.

[image]

Comment: You were right, when should I use @Component annotation?

Comment: yes, or something like `@Bean` , `@Controller` , `@Component` , `@Repository` etc.

Comment: @Jose: @Component is a generic stereotype for the components. @Servcie, @Repository, @Controller extends from @Component: 

`@Service, @Controller, @Repository = {@Component + some more special functionality}`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6897038/8207836