# What will happen if we interchange various annotations like @Service, @Controller and @Repository?

Tags: java, spring, controller

What will happen if we interchange various annotations like @Service, @Controller and @Repository?
I know its the best practice to follow to represent the spring component with these annotations but what happen if we are not doing so ?

Comment: What do you mean? What would you use instead? Only `@Component` or programmatically registering beans?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in
Basically they are both captured as beans, but are intercepted differently, for example @Repository has an extra layer for exception translation

Answer (score 0):

Basically @Component is a generic annotation stereotype and @Service, @Repository and @Controller are just subtypes with a more semantic meaning, at the end of the day with these annotation you are just registering a bean in the spring container and if you exchange those annotations you application is going to work as good as before.

Of course if you have a JpaRepository implementation for example you want to use @Repository annotation instead of @Controller, just for mentioning an example.