# What does the GenericRepository constructor do?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, dependency-injection, autofac

As per my understanding `GenericRepository` is inherited from `IGenericRepository`. It has properties as `IDbFactory DbFactory`, `DBCustomerEntities dbContext` and `DBCustomerEntities DbContext`. We are getting the value for `DBCustomerEntities dbContext` using `Init` method of `IDbFactory`, which is actually initialising database.

My question is why constructor `GenericRepository` is required and what is its role?

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class  
{   
    private DBCustomerEntities dbContext;  

    protected IDbFactory DbFactory  
    { get; private set; }  

    protected DBCustomerEntities DbContext  
    {
        get { return dbContext ?? (dbContext = DbFactory.Init()); }  
    }  

    public GenericRepository(IDbFactory dbFactory)  
    {  
        DbFactory = dbFactory;  
    }  

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()  
    {  
        return DbContext.Set<T>();  
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here, other than to explain some basic C#' code. Perhaps you need to learn what generics are and the functionality of the various types you mention?

Comment: Isn't its role to receive dbFactory from the DI container and assign that to a value stored in the class so that the class can use it? You can contact me for my mailing address to send the prize to.

Comment: The constructor allows the dependency of an instance of `IDbFactory` to be injected into the class for it to use, so that it doesn't have to instantiate it itself and can rely on the instantiating code to decide which implementation of `IDbFactory` it should use. Also, just as a point of interest, `GenericRepository` _implements_ `IGenericRepository` (i.e. provides all of the methods specifed by the `IGenericRepository` interface - it doesn't _inherit_ it, which is a different concept (not trying to be pedantic, they're distinctly different things).

Comment: You need to look up dependency injection, constructor injection, and the repository pattern. The class as it is, is a tricky generic way of implementing standard operations on a table , and as most repository solutions are probably over engineered to save a few lines of code for suspect reasons

Comment: Thanks Diado. Yes, that's right, it implements not inherit (my bad). Thanks for your explaining too.

Comment: Thanks CodeNotFound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why constructor GenericRepository is required and what is it's role?

Because you need to inject an implementation of `IDbFactory` into `GenericRepository` to let it work. Also, you're looking for abstracting *how* `DbContext` is instantiated using a factory, so you don't want to see how the factory is instantiated itself.

IMO, the actual usage of `IDbFactory` seems ugly to just avoid some lines, and it can be solved as follows (which, in fact, saves more lines!):

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class  
{
    public GenericRepository(IDbFactory dbFactory)  
    {  
        DbContext = new Lazy<DBCustomerEntities>(dbFactory.Init);
    } 


    protected Lazy<DBCustomerEntities> DbContext { get; }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll() => DbContext.Value.Set<T>();
    .......
```

When you need to initialize something once only if you access it, you should use `Lazy<T>`.

There's another thing that looks less promising and it's that you're building a repository relying on `IQueryable<T>`. Please see this other Q&A: [Repository design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166888/repository-design-pattern) to get more insights about this topic.